# How to create rounded rectangle window in X11

Tags: linux, x11, embedded-linux

I need to create a rounded rectangle window, but there is api to draw rounded rectangle in X11. Please tell me how to create a rounded rectangle window in X11. Thanks in advance

Comment: Build it from a set of arcs and lines.

Comment: And you probably want to avoid using X11 directly. Toolkits like GTK, Qt, FLTK, FoxToolKit gives you ability to draw thru a wrapping of X11.

Comment: Can you please give me an example for creating round rectangle window using shapes extension library. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [Shape Extension Library](http://www.x.org/docs/Xext/shapelib.pdf).

Comment: Can you please give me an example for creating round rectangle window using shapes extension library. Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi @VigneshK , I've a similar problem, on the web there are few code examples about it and the documentation doesn't explain how to use it properly. However, the most famous source codes you could study are xeyes and oclock, but their original source codes are difficult to find.

Comment: [xeyes](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xorg/app/xeyes) source code for anyone interested. I will update this comment if I figure out what is going on in there.