# How to create round rectangle window in X11

Tags: linux, x11, embedded-linux

How to create round rectangle window in X11 using Shape extension library. Is there any sample for creating rounded rectangle in x11. Please help, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you use some toolkit for that? Qt, GTk, or even Cairo all have some simple API to do this..

Comment: We are creating a user interface application for a embedded board. so lower level coding will give less stress. So that only we are using raw X11 coding. Is there a chance to create a rounded rectangle window in raw X11.?

Comment: Yes it is possible, but why bother? Your coding time (which is related to time to market) is also relevant. If you really insist, look inside the implementation of the toolkits I have mentioned, they are free software and you can study their source code (which is a real example using X11 + Shape). Notice that `cairo` is a small library.... And, as you mentioned, you need X11 + the shape extension....

Comment: [This](https://www.opengroup.org/infosrv/openmotif/R2.1.30/motif/demos/programs/earth/earth.c) is the classic program that uses the shape extension. It uses Motif, the outdated X11 toolkit, but this shouldn't matter. The relevant part is all within `if (XShapeQueryExtension...`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create rounded rectangle window in X11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15562668/how-to-create-rounded-rectangle-window-in-x11)